# Is there a way to improve the quality of the cached images Safari uses for forward/back swiping?

Tags: macos, safari

I know I'm crazy, but it's bugging me.

Comment: I can't see any loss of clarity on a 24" iMac - what sites are you seeing this? How can we try to reproduce this?

Comment: I can confirm - I've seen lossy quality on a 13" MacBook.

Comment: I can confirm on 2011 MacBook Pro both on the color LCD and when connected to my 27" ACD.  It's very noticeable on text links that use the default light blue like on the [Apple Community Support Forums](https://discussions.apple.com/community/mac_os/mac_os_x_v10.7_lion?view=discussions#/?page=3).  The text appears blurry until the page reloads.

Comment: Yeah, it's real. I'm surprised there isn't more talk about this.

Comment: It's bugging me as well. It looks like a screenshot stored in .jpg format. Surprisingly, there're full quality .png preview pictures in ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Webpage Previews/ but Safari doesn't use them.